# How can I hide the save panel when I'm using a NSDocument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nssavepanel

So I'm trying to play around with WebKit and create my own browser.  However, now I'm kind of stuck where I can't hide the save panel when I try to close my window.  I can't find any method in the NSDocument reference that hides the panel.  Does anyone know how I can solve that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to say that `NSDocument` is a slightly odd choice for a browser app. The Cocoa document architecture is really designed for editor-type applications that load and save files from disk, whereas there is no real concept of a "document" in a browser.

Why not just implement a main controller that manages a bunch of window controllers? What does the document architecture give you that you feel your app needs?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I have tried looked into that before, but that seems a bit more complicated than the NSDocument way.  Do you know any sites that can teach that?

Comment: Well, you just need to implement a subclass of `NSWindowController` that manages your browser window. Then you would have some main controller class that manages an `NSMutableArray` containing instances of your `NSWindowController` subclass. Your main controller can respond to menu items like "New Window" by instantiating new instances of the window controller and displaying their windows.